# Сравнение 2 таблиц и обновление в цикле с передачей параметра

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Возникла потребность перенести значения поля из одной таблицы в другую путем сравнения данных.Вот пример таблицы table1

### Table1ID  Table1Name

1. Учебник
2. Тетрадь
3. Учебник
4. Учебник

Пример таблицы table2

### Table2ID  Name    Nameid

1. Ручка
2. Тетрадь
3. Учебник
4. Учебник

Задача: Сравнить 2 таблицы, если в полях значения Name совпадают то добавляем id из таблицы table1 в поле Nameid из table2.
Использую Mysql и php
Мой код

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 , table2 WHERE Table1Name = Table2Name";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$query2 = "UPDATE table2 SET Table2Name=".$row[Table1ID]." WHERE Table1Name = Table2Name";
mysql_query($query2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

по идее, вы можете сделать всё прямо в запросе, без дополнительного кода

```
update Table2 t2 
    join 
       Table1 t1 
    on (Table1Name = Name) 
  set Nameid = t1.id
```

Comment: Дело в том что хотел добавить лимит на записи, так как сервер находится удаленно, в первой таблице 500 записей, во второй около 700...и при попытке запустить выводит ошибку "504 Gateway Time-out".

Comment: Все работает. Спасибо, сервер отключился на несколько минут, но все поменял

Comment: это  очент мало записей, надо заметить. Но хорошо, что получилось